# Clone record with its related list by clicking on custom button on that record ?

Tags: apex, javascript, list-button

i have created one button on record top beside the clone button,
when clicked, execute code that would make a new version record with the same name and append today's date on the end of the name to distinguish it from the original.i created apex class and custom list button but the i clicked on button so java script does'not working on this.so below error occour during click on the button.

How should i do this ?

[image]

Apex class:-

```
global class CloneVersionwithText
{
webservice static void cloneMSAVersion(Id msaId) // you can pass parameters
{ 
   List<MSA_Text_Block__c> MText = new List<MSA_Text_Block__c>();
   Master_Service_Agreement_Version__c msa = [SELECT ID, Name FROM Master_Service_Agreement_Version__c WHERE Id = : msaId];
   Master_Service_Agreement_Version__c msaCopy = msa.clone(false,true);
   msaCopy.Name = msa.Name +'-'+system.today();
   insert msaCopy;
   //cloning Related MSA Text Records
   for(MSA_Text_Block__c c : [SELECT Id, Name, Service__c,         Order_within_Service__c,Master_Service_Agreement_Version__r.ID FROM      MSA_Text_Block__c WHERE Master_Service_Agreement_Version__r.ID = : msa.Id]){
     MSA_Text_Block__c textCopy = c.clone(false,true);
     textCopy.Master_Service_Agreement_Version__r.ID = msaCopy.Id;
     MText.add(textCopy);
    }
   insert MText; 
}
}
```

create a java script button to call the apex class

```
 {!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/30.0/connection.js")}
 {!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/30.0/apex.js")}
 sforce.apex.execute("CloneVersionwithText","cloneMSAVersion",{msaId{!Master_Service_Agreement_Version__c.Id}}"});
```

Answer (score 2):

believe its a syntax issue in passing the parameter to the apex method

you need a semicolon between the parameter name and value.

its always better to declare and initialize your param value and use it wherever you need it.

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/30.0/connection.js")}
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/30.0/apex.js")}

var myParam = "{!Master_Service_Agreement_Version__c.Id}";
sforce.apex.execute("CloneVersionwithText","cloneMSAVersion", {msaId : myParam});
```

Comment: this is not working error show is that : unexpected token and krinshna how to pass id in java script?

Comment: there was an extra } in the code which i removed. updated the answer.

Comment: thank's krishna i solve this error but show new error id is not defined so how can i pass id in this script?

Comment: krishna i need your small help